# How do I precheck some check_boxes in the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Suppose Category has three categories **car,ship,jet**

If the model's **category_list** has already have __'car, ship' __

and **category_list** is

I want to precheck it.

So when I load the form, it should show me like that

## expected form view

```
    [v] car
    [v] ship
    [ ] jet
```

## model/product.rb

```
acts_as_taggable_on :categories
```

## FORM snippet

```
f.inputs "Existing Categories: #{exsisting_categories.to_sentence}" do
  f.input :category_list, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Category.all.map { |category| [category.name, category.id] }, :input_html => { :checked => 'checked' }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that is really simple.

```
Category.all.map { |category| [category.name, category.id, {:checked => (category.name.in? f.object.category_list) }] }
```